# Is there any tools help to reverse jar to java eclispe project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

All, I have a jar file. and I know it is built from a swing project. Becuase I already view some source code of class files of the jar. I want to know if there exists any tools help to convert the jar back to the source project in the eclipse?   Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You mean a decompiler?

Comment: Yes .. I can view the source of the single class . But I need to reverse the jar to an eclipse project. thanks.

Comment: In the need of same tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jd.benow.ca

1. Drag and drop jar file into JD GUI decompiler
2. select File-> Save all sources

Answer (score 0):

7zip will allow you to view the contents of the jar, including source files if they are there. Lots of decompilers exist to decompile the class files. My favorite is jd-gui (http://jd.benow.ca/).

You can also add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Uthen under tje Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and select the jar file. Alternatively you can add a lib directory to your project and put a copy of the jar there.

But as far as converting a jar file into an eclipse project, you could extract the files with 7zip or other tool, then import them into a new eclipse project.